# SQL - update records within select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Say you are joining two tables but one of the columns you are selecting you want to update with new values, do you have to do that as two separate statements or can you embed an update statement within the select query?

i.e.

```
SELECT table1.xxx, table1.yyy, table2.zzz
FROM table1 JOIN
      table2
     ON table1.xxx = table2.zzz
WHERE table1.xxx = 'Y'

UPDATE table1
    SET xxx = 'YES'
    WHERE xxx = 'Y'
```

Does that make sense or do you need to do the update statement and then do the select query separately?

Comment: An `UPDATE` statement does not return values.  A `SELECT` statement does not modify data.  You cannot do both in a single statement.

Comment: so basically..you want to form a new table with the union of old two..but one particular column needs to be modified ?

Comment: Is it two separate query or single query?

Comment: Rohitas, yes that's right.

Comment: Jack, I guess I was asking if you could do it as one query or you normally do it as two and I think Gordon has answered that it should be two separate commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need  the join for filter the rows you need to update you can use Update with join  eg:

```
  UPDATE table1
  JOIN  table2  ON table1.xxx = table2.zzz
  SET table1.xxx = 'YES'
  WHERE table1.xxx = 'Y'
```